# Simpler way to perform a row/column lookup in Excel, where columns with data are of variable lengths?

Tags: excel, lookup-tables

I have Excel data that looks like this:

```
      CHEVY_12       FORD_12        FORD_13        CHEVY_13
t1    462.0646058    5.507611655    887.4193417    197.1054415
t2    427.4865042    646.2186952                   685.0746363
t3    175.4137935                                  73.77079157
```

The columns are all mixed up, and the column headers aren't in any meaningful order.

My goal is to put the data from this table into a table so that it looks like this:

```
<cell A1>  Chevy          Ford
2012       175.4137935     646.2186952
2013        73.77079157     887.4193417
```

However, in the data table, not all of the columns have data for `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`, so a straight `HLOOKUP` doesn't work. Basically the procedure I'm trying to use has four parts (all formulas assume we're talking about the Chevy 2012 cell, but see the attached screenshot for all the gory details):

- Create the column header that's going to be looked up in the data table. Assuming the results table has its leftmost corner in cell A1 (as shown), I did this with `=CONCATENATE(UPPER(B$1), "_", MID($A2, 3, 2))` in the first cell (Chevy, 2012), etc. as shown.
- Find the column in the data table with a header that matches the header constructed in step 1. I just used `=MATCH(B3, $F$6:$I$6, 0)` for this.
- Find the last row with data in each column, based on the column header. I used `=MATCH(9E+307, OFFSET($E$6, 1, B9, MATCH(REPT("z", 255), $E$7:$E$9), 1))` for this. Since I don't know the maximum number of rows going in (in other words, how many `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, etc. I'm going to have), I had to find the last row with text in the row labels as well. I used formulas from [this link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/last_value.php) to find the last number (`MATCH(9E+307,range)`) or text (`MATCH(REPT("z",255),range)`) in a range.
- Use the pieces constructed above to perform the final `HLOOKUP` in the data table.

Here is the final spreadsheet:

[image: spreadsheet]

The data table is located in cells `$E$6:$I$9` and looks like this:

[image: data table]

**Is there a simpler way to perform a lookup like this?** I combined all of these pieces into one formula, like this (the example formula looks up the data for Chevy, 2012):

```
=HLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(UPPER(B$2), "_", MID($A3, 3, 2)), $F$6:$I$9, MATCH(9E+307, OFFSET($E$6, 1, MATCH(CONCATENATE(UPPER(B$2), "_", MID($A3, 3, 2)), $F$6:$I$6, 0), MATCH(REPT("z", 255), $E$7:$E$9), 1)) + 1)
```

but obviously that's really messy, and I'm wondering if there is a simpler way. I'd like to do this with one formula (as in the last example), but that last formula does things I don't like, like performing the concatenation twice). I'm using Excel 2013.

Comment: How about just cleaning up the data to a database type format? Is that something you can work with?

Comment: So your existing formula works but you want something that looks simpler?  I have to agree with @nutsch that if you want the formula to be cleaner the input data has to be cleaner.

Comment: @nutsch Unfortunately no. A ton of different teams at my firm use this dataset, and they rely on it being in *this*, less-than-optimal format. I'm not able to change the dataset just for my purposes because I risk breaking a lot of the other processes in the firm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *User Defined Function*.

Something like

```
Function MyUDF(Brand As Variant, Yr As Variant, Data As Range) As Variant
    Dim Hdr As String
    Dim DataCol As Long

    Hdr = UCase(Brand) & "_" & Right$(Yr, 2)
    DataCol = Application.Match(Hdr, Data.Rows(1), 0)
    With Data.Columns(DataCol)
        If Len(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)) = 0 Then
            MyUDF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        Else
            MyUDF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Called like this (based on your sample data addresses) and copied to the required range

```
=MyUDF(B$2,$A3,$E$6:$I$9)
```